# Software to plot curve from function for area calculation

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, mathematical-physics, math-software

I am looking for any software to plot a function of curve and line and shade the area bound by curve and line. [image: Graph Example]

I use desmos till now, but I want to plot smooth graph as shown in figure and i couldn't find any software that can plot such smooth graph.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: uh, shooting from hip: metapost, matplotlib with python, tikz

Comment: I like and use Mathematica but it's not for free. In my opinion the best free softwares are Desmos and Geogebra. (I believe Desmos can plot this graph without any problems.)

Comment: Desmos and Geogebra does the job but since I will be using this graph for my book to be published so i wanted graph to be smooth as given above.

Comment: What about SAGE?

Comment: As has already been mentioned, there are lots of options. Since you're already accustomed to Desmos, it's worth mentioning that you can plot this particular graph [like so](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hkcpvhkank).